# Low Accuracy in Deep Learning Classification Model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, tensorflow2.0

I was making a project on Deep Learning classification Model. I used 100 dancing and 100 walking videos and made a classification model which would predict whether a new input will belong to Dancing Class or Walking Class. My model is showing an accuracy of 50%. I am not able to increase it, tried increasing datasets, changed some of the hyper parameters still no results. Please someone help me I would be grateful to you.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

dataset_path = os.listdir('dataset/train')

label_types = os.listdir('dataset/train')
label_types.remove('.ipynb_checkpoints')
print (label_types) 



rooms = []

for item in dataset_path:
 #file names
 all_rooms = os.listdir('dataset/train' + '/' +item)

 # Appending to listt
 for room in all_rooms:
    rooms.append((item, str('dataset/train' + '/' +item) + '/' + room))
    
#Dataframe        
train_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rooms, columns=['tag', 'video_name'])
print(train_df.head())
print(train_df.tail())


df = train_df.loc[:,['video_name','tag']]
df
df.to_csv('train.csv')

dataset_path = os.listdir('dataset/test')
print(dataset_path)

room_types = os.listdir('dataset/test')
print("Types of activities found: ", len(dataset_path))

rooms = []

for item in dataset_path:
 # Extracting file names
 all_rooms = os.listdir('dataset/test' + '/' +item)

 # Appending to list
 for room in all_rooms:
    rooms.append((item, str('dataset/test' + '/' +item) + '/' + room))
    
#Dataframe        
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rooms, columns=['tag', 'video_name'])
print(test_df.head())
print(test_df.tail())

df = test_df.loc[:,['video_name','tag']]
df
df.to_csv('test.csv')

from tensorflow_docs.vis import embed
from tensorflow import keras
from imutils import paths

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import imageio
import cv2
import os

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
    try:
        tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
        gpus[0],[tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=5120)])
    except RuntimeError as e:
        print(e)

train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

print(f"Total videos for training: {len(train_df)}")
print(f"Total videos for testing: {len(test_df)}")


train_df.sample(10)

IMG_SIZE = 224


def crop_center_square(frame):
    y, x = frame.shape[0:2]
    min_dim = min(y, x)
    start_x = (x // 2) - (min_dim // 2)
    start_y = (y // 2) - (min_dim // 2)
    return frame[start_y : start_y + min_dim, start_x : start_x + min_dim]


def load_video(path, max_frames=0, resize=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE)):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
    frames = []
    try:
        while True:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if not ret:
                break
            frame = crop_center_square(frame)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, resize)
            frame = frame[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
            frames.append(frame)

            if len(frames) == max_frames:
                break
    finally:
        cap.release()
    return np.array(frames)

def build_feature_extractor():
    feature_extractor = keras.applications.InceptionV3(
        weights="imagenet",
        include_top=False,
        pooling="avg",
        input_shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3),
    )
    preprocess_input = keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input

    inputs = keras.Input((IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
    preprocessed = preprocess_input(inputs)

    outputs = feature_extractor(preprocessed)
    return keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="feature_extractor")


feature_extractor = build_feature_extractor()


label_processor = keras.layers.StringLookup(num_oov_indices=0, vocabulary=np.unique(train_df["tag"]))
print(label_processor.get_vocabulary())

labels = train_df["tag"].values
labels = label_processor(labels[..., None]).numpy()
labels

IMG_SIZE = 224
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS = 100

MAX_SEQ_LENGTH = 100
NUM_FEATURES = 2048


def prepare_all_videos(df, root_dir):
    num_samples = len(df)
    video_paths = df["video_name"].values.tolist()
    
    ##take all classlabels from train_df column named 'tag' and store in labels
    labels = df["tag"].values
    
    #convert classlabels to label encoding
    labels = label_processor(labels[..., None]).numpy()

    # `frame_masks` and `frame_features` are what we will feed to our sequence model.
    # `frame_masks` will contain a bunch of booleans denoting if a timestep is
    # masked with padding or not.
    frame_masks = np.zeros(shape=(num_samples, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH), dtype="bool") # 145,20
    frame_features = np.zeros(shape=(num_samples, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, NUM_FEATURES), dtype="float32") #145,20,2048

    # For each video.
    for idx, path in enumerate(video_paths):
        # Gather all its frames and add a batch dimension.
        frames = load_video(os.path.join(root_dir, path))
        frames = frames[None, ...]

        # Initialize placeholders to store the masks and features of the current video.
        temp_frame_mask = np.zeros(shape=(1, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,), dtype="bool")
        temp_frame_features = np.zeros(
            shape=(1, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, NUM_FEATURES), dtype="float32"
        )

        # Extract features from the frames of the current video.
        for i, batch in enumerate(frames):
            video_length = batch.shape[0]
            length = min(MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, video_length)
            for j in range(length):
                temp_frame_features[i, j, :] = feature_extractor.predict(
                    batch[None, j, :]
                )
            temp_frame_mask[i, :length] = 1  # 1 = not masked, 0 = masked

        frame_features[idx,] = temp_frame_features.squeeze()
        frame_masks[idx,] = temp_frame_mask.squeeze()

    return (frame_features, frame_masks), labels


train_data, train_labels = prepare_all_videos(train_df, "train")
test_data, test_labels = prepare_all_videos(test_df, "test")

print(f"Frame features in train set: {train_data[0].shape}")
print(f"Frame masks in train set: {train_data[1].shape}")



print(f"train_labels in train set: {train_labels.shape}")

print(f"test_labels in train set: {test_labels.shape}")



# Create Adam Optimizer

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

opt_1 = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)



# Utility for our sequence model.
def get_sequence_model():
    class_vocab = label_processor.get_vocabulary()

    frame_features_input = keras.Input((MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, NUM_FEATURES))
    mask_input = keras.Input((MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,), dtype="bool")

    # Refer to the following tutorial to understand the significance of using `mask`:
    # https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/gru/
    x = keras.layers.GRU(16, return_sequences=True)(frame_features_input, mask=mask_input)
    x = keras.layers.GRU(8)(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.4)(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="relu")(x)
    output = keras.layers.Dense(len(class_vocab), activation="softmax")(x)

    rnn_model = keras.Model([frame_features_input, mask_input], output)

    rnn_model.compile(
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    return rnn_model

EPOCHS = 100
# Utility for running experiments.
def run_experiment():
    filepath = "./tmp/video_classifier"
    checkpoint = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath, save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, verbose=1
    )

    seq_model = get_sequence_model()
    history = seq_model.fit(
        [train_data[0], train_data[1]],
        train_labels,
        validation_split=0.5,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        callbacks=[checkpoint],
    )

    seq_model.load_weights(filepath)
    _, accuracy = seq_model.evaluate([test_data[0], test_data[1]], test_labels)
    print(f"Test accuracy: {round(accuracy * 100, 2)}%")

    return history, seq_model


_, sequence_model = run_experiment()



def prepare_single_video(frames):
    frames = frames[None, ...]
    frame_mask = np.zeros(shape=(1, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH,), dtype="bool")
    frame_features = np.zeros(shape=(1, MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, NUM_FEATURES), dtype="float32")

    for i, batch in enumerate(frames):
        video_length = batch.shape[0]
        length = min(MAX_SEQ_LENGTH, video_length)
        for j in range(length):
            frame_features[i, j, :] = feature_extractor.predict(batch[None, j, :])
        frame_mask[i, :length] = 1  # 1 = not masked, 0 = masked

    return frame_features, frame_mask


def sequence_prediction(path):
    class_vocab = label_processor.get_vocabulary()

    frames = load_video(os.path.join("test", path))
    frame_features, frame_mask = prepare_single_video(frames)
    probabilities = sequence_model.predict([frame_features, frame_mask])[0]

    for i in np.argsort(probabilities)[::-1]:
        print(f"  {class_vocab[i]}: {probabilities[i] * 100:.2f}%")
    return frames

test_video = np.random.choice(test_df["video_name"].values.tolist())
print(f"Test video path: {test_video}")

test_frames = sequence_prediction(test_video)
```